# Getting an empty result when trying to get JSON twitter timeline but it works when I copy and paste it into a browser

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm using the following to try and get the twitter timeline of a user.  When I view the network traffic in Firebug it shows a 200 response code, but the line is red and the results are blank.  If I take the same url and paste it into a browser I get the json as expected.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  You can see I put an alert inside there and it's never hit.  I get no javascript error either though, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=10&screen_name=name_removed&include_rts=true', function(data) 
{
    alert('test');
    var items = [];

    //Code to handle result
});
```

I've checked this in Firebug and the IE developer tools.  Firebug shows it in red as if there was a problem but a 200 reponse code.  IE developer tools and fiddler don't even show the URL was ever called.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe u need to use the https protocol? I don't see anything wrong in the code though.

Comment: Tried using https, no difference.

Comment: you can't do cross domain ajax calls like this. when you are doing it from a browsers it isn't an ajax call so it works

Comment: @Abid I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm doing almost this exact same thing on another website.  The only difference is what I'm doing with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this(if this is the same error I'm thinking of).

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=10&screen_name=name_removed&include_rts=true?callback=?',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The callback parameter is important.

Please see this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: It was the callback parameter, I didn't add it back on when I changed the url.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)